# using the old input of Form::password laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

in my blade i have this change password function i wanted it to "display" the old password when the user have errors like for example the user entered nothing and clicked submit so here is the code in my blade

```
<div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('cpass', 'Current Password') }} <span style="color:red"><i>{{ $errors->first('cpass', ':message') }}</i></span>
                        {{ Form::password('cpass',  array('class' => 'form-control' , 'placeholder'=>'enter current password') , Input::old('cpass') ) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('npass', 'New Password') }} <span style="color:red"><i>{{ $errors->first('npass', ':message') }}</i></span>
                        {{ Form::password('npass', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'enter new password'), Input::old('npass') ) }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ Form::label('rpass', 'Re-type new Password') }} <span style="color:red"><i>{{ $errors->first('rpass', ':message') }}</i></span>
                        {{ Form::password('rpass', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'re-type new password'), Input::old('rpass') ) }}
                    </div>
```

in my controller i throw it like this

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('User_Profile')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::all());
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

i dont know why im not getting the old input from the user. what may be the wrong im doing? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form builder password method doesn't accept any input besides the name of the password field and its attributes:

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_password

You'll need to do this with javascript by setting the value of the password field manually on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#rpass').val("{{ Input::old('rpass') }}");
    });
</script>
```